# get cURL with 2 Parameters php

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm really confused with cURL..

example :

i can access with my old cURL code

> cikpoo.com/Member/cardnumber/$card_number

but if i want to access like that

> cikpoo.com/Member/cardnumber/$card_number/dateSEP/$date

how to code that??

this is my code

```
foreach($member_data as $row){

$cardnumber=$row->cardnumber;
$date=$row->date;
                                }
if($cardnumber==''){
echo "enter your card number";
}else{

$url = $data_b->service_url; //url is cikpoo.com/

   $ch = curl_init($url.'Member/cardnumber/'. $cardnumber .'/dateSEP/'. $date ); //problem here
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_header);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $result = curl_exec($ch);//json file
                curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Might need to put in the http:// or https://

Comment: yes, my url is http:// cikpoo.com in table data_b

Comment: I don't see a problem with the concatenation. What error are you getting?

Answer (score -1):

This example has some error reporting in it. This is not meant to be an answer. Just a working example with error checking.

```
    $url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/';

    $curl = curl_init($url .'js/ajax_info.txt');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    if(!$result){
        echo('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    echo '<br>'.$result;
```

Comment: hi.. if i want access this example site https://cikpoo.com/Member/cardnumber/[$card_number], with just 1 string(Member/cardnumber) and 1 parameter ($card_number). I just type this code "$ch = curl_init($url.'Member/cardnumber/'. $cardnumber);" right? my question is, if i want get access to https://cikpoo.com/Member/cardnumber/[$card_number]/dateSEP/[$date]. with 2 string(Member/cardnumber and /dateSEP/) and 2 parameter ($card_number and $date). what code i should type?

Comment: I cant tell you details about the API your calling. Because I have no detail on it. Need to know what errors you are getting.